# SQL: LIMIT executed before DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, distinct

I am doing a custom WordPress query and I need to have pagination on the results. 
For testing purposes limit is set to 2. When there are 4 unique results WP displays only 1 result on the first page and in the total of the results it misses the last result.

I guess the problem is in the result of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT* 
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
WHERE wp_posts.post_status ='publish'
AND wp_posts.post_type ='directory_listing'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82) 
ORDERBY wp_posts.post_title ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

When I execute this directly on MySQL it returns two duplicates instead of the two first unique results.

Am I doing this the wrong way? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I"m not familiar with wordpress; does a group by execute before the limit?

Comment: You probably do not get exact duplicates. But only `wp_posts.*` columns are same while the `wp_term_relationships.*` columns are different. Right?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying the above query returns a non-distinct result set?

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` is (or should be, unless there is a bug) always executed after `SELECT DISTINCT`. My guess is that your query does NOT show exact duplicates, it's only showing duplicate `wp_posts` columns that have more than 1 related rows in the `wp_term_relationships` table, meaning they have more than one related taxonomies.

I also guess that you only need the `wp_posts.*` columns. Try this which also gets rid of the `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM wp_posts AS p
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM wp_term_relationships AS r
        WHERE p.ID = r.object_id  
          AND r.term_taxonomy_id IN 
              ( 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73
              , 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82) 
      )
  AND p.post_status ='publish'
  AND p.post_type ='directory_listing'
ORDER BY p.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

If you also want the taxonomies or other columns from the `wp_term_relationships` table, you'd have to use your `JOIN` query and `GROUP BY` the `wp_posts.id`:

```
SELECT p.* 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(r.term_taxonomy_id) AS taxonomy_ids
     , COUNT(*) AS number_of_taxonomies
FROM wp_posts AS p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS r
    ON p.ID = r.object_id 
WHERE p.post_status ='publish'
  AND p.post_type ='directory_listing'
  AND r.term_taxonomy_id IN 
              ( 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73
              , 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82) 
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0 , 2
```

Comment: Now I'm not so experienced in SQL, is the above way, using WHERE EXISTS, the better option instead of doing a JOIN?

Comment: If you remove the `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `COUNT()` lines, the two queries would yield the same results. You can test them with your data (when you have enough, say, more than a few thousand rows), count speed, see the plan for both of them using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and check how (and if) indexes are used. Which is fatser, depends on many factors, including your exact MySQL version, memory and other db settings, size and distribution of your tables, etc. I'd prefer the `EXISTS` unless it is tested slower than the `JOIN` version (after both are optimized).

Comment: `EXISTS` is not better by definiton that a `JOIN`, it returns different results. It's usually how a semi-join is done. See here: http://awads.net/wp/2007/05/01/back-to-basics-anti-joins-and-semi-joins/